# compare the values of a df column with a single value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare all values of column A `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))`with a single value say 55 and get a count all the numbers that are greater than or equal to the single value.

The following code has not worked out for me so far

```
ctr=0
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))
if (df['A'].any() >= 55):
    ctr+=1
print(ctr)
```

Comment: You really need to review the pandas user guide to understand pandas dataframes and pandas series better. `df.query('A >= 55').count()[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum(df['A'] >= 55)
```

This works because `True` is counted as 1 in a sum operation and `False` as zero.